# Angular/Ionic going back to the state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an article list page where I have filters for articles, latest and popular. 
Their buttons look like that in the front page:

```
<a class="button button-icon" href="#" ng-click="articleFilter('latest')"><i class="ion-ios-circle-filled" ng-show="bulletpointLatest"></i> Latest
      </a>
<a class="button button-icon" href="#" ng-click="articleFilter()"><i class="ion-ios-circle-filled" ng-show="bulletpointPopular"></i> Popular
      </a>
```

I have set up the filters in my FrontPageController that looks like this:

```
  .controller('FrontPageController', function($scope, ArticleService, $state, $ionicScrollDelegate, $location, $ionicPosition) {
  ArticleService.all().then(function(data){
    $scope.articles = data;
  });

  $scope.$on('$ionicParentView.afterEnter', function(event, data) {
    if (data.direction == 'back') {
      $scope.doRefresh();
    }
  });

  $scope.bulletpointSiste = true;

  $scope.articleFilter = function(button){
    if (button == "siste"){
      $scope.bulletpointSiste = true;
      $scope.bulletpointPopular = false;
      ArticleService.all().then(function(data){
        $scope.articles = data;
      });
    }
    else {
      $scope.bulletpointSiste = false;
      $scope.bulletpointPopular = true;
      ArticleService.popular().then(function(data){
        $scope.articles = data;
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  };

  $scope.like = function(article){
    article.like = article.like == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    ArticleService.like(article.id)
  };

  $scope.doRefresh = function (){
    ArticleService.all().then(function(data){
      $scope.articles = data;
    })
    .finally(function() {
       $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
     });
  };
})
```

My config for the front page route is:

```
.state('main.front', {
    url: '/front',
    views: {
      'content': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/main-front.html',
        controller: 'FrontPageController'
      }
    },
    authenticate: true
  })
```

In my article page view I have tried to go back to the front page by using ng-click.

```
<a ng-click="goBack()" nav-direction="back">
```

And in my article controller I tried with ionic history:

```
$scope.goBack = function(){
    $ionicHistory.goBack()
  };
```

**Update**

Now, since I am refreshing articles on back with:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicParentView.afterEnter', function(event, data) {
    if (data.direction == 'back') {
      $scope.doRefresh();
    }
  });
```

I need that in order to change the style for like icons if they were clicked in an article page that they get an appropriate style for that. Since `doRefresh()` function gets all the latest articles:

```
$scope.doRefresh = function (){
    ArticleService.all().then(function(data){
      $scope.articles = data;
    })
    .finally(function() {
       $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
     });
  };
```

I need to somehow make it work so that I know what was the previous state so that I can call appropriate service on refresh, popular if the user is coming from an article that he opened on the list of popular articles.
How should I do that?

Comment: I think it should work automatically thanks to views caching but I'm not sure... Did you disable the cache in your application ?

Comment: I didn't disable it

Answer (score 0):

@Marco: Can you change your goBack function to the following code with input the front view state name.

```
var goBack = function() {
   $state.go('VIEW_NAME');//
}
```

Because my experience is the view will always be cached unless we disable it.

Refer [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/)

Comment: But also returns back to the front page which has a controller FrontPageController which in return loads first all of the latest articles, so that is not what I need

Comment: @Marco: so you mean you put a function to load all article under ng-init of front view, is this ?

Comment: I have edited my question with the code from the FrontPageController, there you can see I call ArticleService.all() which returns all the latest articles, so I need to somehow make that it returns either popular or latest articles based on what was the latest state when the user is coming back to the front page.

Comment: I am confused now. So let say If I access the front page since 9AM, it will load the data at 9PM, and I select to filter by popular article only. Next I go somewhere and go back to front page at 9:20AM. It will display the latest data at 9:20AM but this set of data hasn't already filtered by popular article only ?

Comment: I hope the update part of my question helps, since I am using function to refresh articles on back click, I need to make somehow, that it remebers where the user came from and then refresh the articles with an appropriate filter on. Because, yes, you were right, if I leave out my doRefresh() function that it will get me back to the right state, but the problem is that I need to refresh the page because of the like icons.